# Only get lines containing specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an Ajax get call to an API to gather logs in txt format and print them on a webpage. 
I want to only print lines containing a specific string (USER_LOG) and if possible only everything after USER_LOG and nothing that may come before it.

This is what I'm using to get the logs printed on the page.

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://Path/to/API/log",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Auth"
      },
      method: 'GET',
      contentType: 'text/plain',
      success: function(data){
            $("#logs").html(data);
        $('#logs').animate({scrollTop: $('#logs')[0].scrollHeight}, 2000);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $("#button").prop("disabled", true);
      }
    });
```

I thought something like this would work but I haven't had any luck. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so any help would be appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://Path/to/API/log",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Auth"
      },
      method: 'GET',
      contentType: 'text/plain',
      success: function(data){
      var lines = data.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) 
         {
          if (lines.indexOf("USER_LOG") != -1) 
          {
            $("#logs").html(lines);
          }
        }
      },
      error: function (error) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $("#button").prop("disabled", true);
      }
    });
```

Comment: how big is the log file? You are not using the i value in for loop, it should be lines[i].indexOf

Comment: It varies but not very large. That did the trick. Do you know how I could get the line printed to start at or after USER_LOG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
//I added this array to simulate the API response
var data = "line 1 USER_LOG TEXT TO PRINT \n line 2 USER_LOG TEXT TO PRINT 2";

var lines = data.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
  {
    var line = lines[i]; //extract the single line, in your snipet you were trying to print the whole array
   {
    if (line.indexOf("USER_LOG") != -1) 
    {
      //get only the text after 'USER_LOG' for the single line
      var textToPrint = line.split('USER_LOG')[1];
      //instead of replacing the html with .html() use append()
      $("#logList").append("<li>"+textToPrint+"</li>");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="logs">
<ul id="logList"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted. other than the html and <li> this was 100% what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: you are welcome. I would be interested to know why someone downvoted even the solution, at least to improve the use of this portal, but I guess education is a rare resource nowadays.

Comment: This is a great solution however I'm getting duplicated lines when appending. Any solutions to solve that? I've tried an if last!= statement bit to no avail.

Comment: are these replicated lines inside the response you get from the server? can you provide and example of what inside your "data" variable?